# How to get Realtime Database in Firebase by using cloud function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've created Firebase project and added some data to Realtime Database? I also created cloud functions by using console. This is my following code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

 const snapshott = await admin.database().ref('/messages').push({"original":"ZXz"});

 res.send("assasin")
});
exports.getMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    const snapshott = await admin.database().ref('/messages').get();

    res.send(snapshott)
});
```

The `addMessage` function works fine but `getMessage` function gives an error.

This is the following error

> ```
> TypeError: admin.database(...).ref(...).get is not a function
>     at exports.addMessage.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:15:60)
>     at <anonymous>
>     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
> ```

So how can I get Realtime Database in Firebase by using cloud function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you will see in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference), there is no `get()` method for a Realtime Database `Reference`. On the other hand, Firestore, the other NoSQL Database offered by Firebase has a [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method. You are probably mixing up the two database services :-)

To read a node in the Realtime Database, you need to use the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#once) method.

So, in your case you would do as follows:

```
exports.getMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    const snapshott = await admin.database().ref('/messages').once('value');

    res.send(snapshott);

});
```

Two extra things to note:

1. You can also use the [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#on) method to read a node, but this method is not commonly used in Cloud Functions, since it sets a listener which **continuously** "listens for data changes at a particular location".
2. You should manage errors in your Cloud Function, see this official video: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series#learn-javascript-promises-pt1-with-http-triggers-in-cloud-functions

Comment: "this method is not adapted to Cloud Functions" -> "this method not commonly used in Cloud Functions"